# Joining a table (or not) based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the three tables following in my SQL Server 2008 database:

- Cars
- Drivers
- UnavailableDrivers

What I want is to show unavailableDrivers to the end users if they set @isAvailable = 0. On the other hand, if isAvailable=1, then the end user should see only available drivers. Finally, if isAvailable is NULL then the user should see all the drivers.

```
declare @isAvailable bit;
```

I need to write a query like that:

```
Select * 
From Cars c
Inner join Drivers d on (c.driverId = d.Id)
CASE 
   WHEN @isAvailable = 0 THEN inner join UnavailableDrivers uc on (c.driverId= uc.Id)
   WHEN @isAvailable = 1 THEN inner join UnavailableDrivers uc on (c.driverId != uc.Id)
   ELSE @IsAvailable END
-- ELSE -> basically DO NOT JOIN UnavailableDrivers
```

It is giving incorrect syntax error and I couldn't find the right syntax for a few hours unfortunately. Actually I don't feel the query is right either. So any help to fix my query on this logic would be appreciated!

Comment: SELECT 
FROM Cars c
LEFT JOIN Drivers d
    ON c.DriverId = d.DriverId
LEFT JOIN UnavailableDrivers u
    ON u.DriverId = c.DriverId

Comment: you will need to apply the logic via dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query do you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars c
INNER JOIN Drivers d ON (c.driverId = d.Id)
WHERE (@isAvailable IS NULL) -- will not join to UnavailableDrivers is isAvailable is null
OR (@isAvailable = 0 AND c.driverId IN (SELECT uc.id FROM UnavailableDrivers uc)) -- will join to UnavailableDrivers only if isAvailable equals to 0
OR (@isAvailable = 1 AND c.driverId NOT IN (SELECT uc.id FROM UnavailableDrivers uc)) -- will join to UnavailableDrivers because isAvailable equals to 1
```

Comment: My friend I wanna ask you something. When the `NOT IN` part is working (@isAvailable=1), the running time is higher than the others (It is 42 seconds while the others are 14-16 seconds). Could you advise a way to fix this issue as well, maybe? @CodeNotFound

Comment: replace it with `(@isAvailable = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT uc.id FROM UnavailableDrivers uc WHERE uc.id = c.driverId))`

Answer (score 0):

Terrible approach, but you asked for it

```
USE [DB]
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [GetDrivers]
        @isAvailable bit
    AS
    BEGIN


            IF (@isAvailable = 0)
            BEGIN
                Select * From Cars c
                    Inner join Drivers d on (c.driverId = d.Id)
                    inner join UnavailableDrivers uc on (c.driverId= uc.Id)

            END
            ELSE
            begin
                Select * From Cars c
                    Inner join Drivers d on (c.driverId = d.Id)
                    inner join UnavailableDrivers uc on (c.driverId!= uc.Id)

            end



    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  *
  , CASE 
   WHEN d.DriverId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Availible'
   WHEN u.DriverId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Unavailible'
   ELSE 'Driver is in both'
   AS 'Driver Status'
FROM Cars c
 LEFT JOIN Drivers d
   ON c.DriverId = d.DriverId
 LEFT JOIN UnavailableDrivers u
   ON u.DriverId = c.DriverId
```